# Is it possible to separate blockchain and wallet functions?

Tags: blockchain, security

I'm looking for a way to use bitcoin-core in monero-way (It uses separate blockchain daemon and wallet daemon).

I'd like to run bitcoin-qt interface on my laptop and connect to external node with full blockchain. In this way I can share my full node with other people and my wallet will be safe.

Is it possible to use bitcoin-core in this way?

P.S.: I listen about electrum-server, but I don't want to use another software.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use bitcoin-core in this way?

No. bitcoin-qt is a completely standalone software that includes all of bitcoind's functionality. It does not start bitcoind in the background nor does it connect to a background daemon.

Comment: I know that this is not in the basic configuration. Perhaps there are highly specialized hacks for this?

Comment: You can run a node on a server and then run another node on your machine which only connects to that one. But the node on your machine would still have to download and verify the blockchain (you can prune it so it does not take up as much disk space).